# Alternatives for QC

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration, qtp, hp-quality-center

In my project we are using QC to execute our test cases(QTP), moving forward we would be eliminating QC (for cost reasons).

As far as I explored MSBuild & Jenkins, they would be suitable.

But MSBuild will trigger the execution when a new build pushed to the repository. Also it will automatically test on the latest build.

Is there any other CI tool available to execute test cases through QTP?

I will be executing automation once in a release. Also we install our application by manual since it requires lots of configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [HP Application Automation Tools](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HP+Application+Automation+Tools).

This plugin basically replaces the need for QC, and is developed by HP.

Create a Jenkins job using this plugin on the same Jenkins installation used to build your code, then you can configure your job to run your tests as soon the code is available (e.g. on a nightly basis).

See [here](https://sumeetkushwah.com/2015/03/24/implementing-ci-using-jenkins-and-uft/) for a helpful guide on how to implement a simple Jenkins job using this plugin.

They also host the code on [Github](https://github.com/hpsa/hp-application-automation-tools-plugin), which is very useful if you need to change the behavior of the plugin to suit your needs.

Comment: It seems like we need to have Quality center client installed in the machine. but in my case we are going to eliminate QC. if this is the case will this Jenkins plugins support for my criteria?

Comment: I use the plugin without QC installed and it works great. Admittedly, the documentation HP provides can be a bit confusing as it seems to suggest you need it installed, you don't. I have updated my answer with a couple of links to help you get started.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information. It's really saved my time as well as cost 

Comment: You're welcome, I was in your shoes not so long ago! QC is very expensive, and this plugin is free, an easy choice to make :)